# How to track various JS parameters (memory profiling, flame graphs, cpu) in various browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, profiling

I'm creating a tool to test UI performance. It currently:

- populates the data inside the database;
- logs into the application;
- accesses the page multiple times and measures the time of each access;
- calculates avg, max, min, first access time and so on;
- the testing application / script leverages selenium.

The app is JS heavy, uses a lot of ajax, data processing in the UI, heavy websockets. So I would like to measure various parameters that the browser tab running the app when its access:

- cpu;
- memory (private working set primarily);

**Question:** What would be good tools to use for that, maybe to integrate with the script? Any tools or approaches (maybe writing something of my own) for JS profiling?

I have read about dynaTrace AJAX, but the project is EOL / deprecated so looking for similar suggestions and general advice how to approach the problem.

My current approach is to catch the process for the tab running the app during it's creation and monitor the memory size every 500ms with something like [PsList](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pslist.aspx)

Comment: Why not just use Dev Tools? It has all of the profiling capabilities you listed

Comment: Indeed they provide the capabilities. However I need the metric collected in an automated fashion and integrated with the tool. As far as I can tell there is no possibility to get data through CLI from dev tools that run in the browser, unless doing something like this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating